# Unable to receive multiple clients data using ZeroMQ

Tags: python, zeromq, distributed-system

I am executing this program of server, receiving from multiple clients, but after the first message for one client, the server is receiving the data and then it does not wait for other client request and just display the first clients data and stops.

Also, I am unable to be a client from other VM, which uses the same linux machine. I am not sure how to modify it in order to let the server receive from more clients.

1.I am running the same client program in different VM-s and trying to send the data to the server. Only one client message is delivered and other client is unable to send and just waits.

Thanks

```
import zmq
import json

ports = ["192.168.1.24:10000"]

context = zmq.Context()
print("Connecting to server")
socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
for port in ports:
    socket.connect("tcp://%s" % port)
    print("Successfully connected to server %s" % port)

for request in range(len(ports)):
    print("Sending request ", request, "...")
    socket.send_string("", zmq.SNDMORE) 
    socket.send_string("Sensor Data") 

    # use poll for timeouts:
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

    socks = dict(poller.poll(5 * 1000))

    if socket in socks:
        try:
            socket.recv()  # discard delimiter
            msg_json = socket.recv()  # actual message
            sens = json.loads(msg_json)
            response = "am: %s :: pam: %s :: dam: %s" % (sens['a'], sens['b'], sens['c'])
            print("Received reply ", request, "[", response, "]")
        except IOError:
            print("Could not connect to machine")
    else:
        print("Machine did not respond")
```

Client:

```
import zmq
import time
import json

port = "10000"

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)

while True:
    #  Wait for next request from server
    message = str(socket.recv(), "utf-8")
    print("Received request: ", message)
    time.sleep(1)
    msgDict = {
        'am': "990",
        'pam': "11",
        'dam': "1",
    }
    ms = json.dumps(msgDict)
    socket.send_string(ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few details that seem not to be well orchestrated inside your flow of events:

Given your code, the client-side makes a single **`.send_string( json.dumps( msgDict ) )`**

but on the server-side, your code does two consecutive **`.recv()`**-s, both of which are blocking.

So what happens is that after having read-out a message from the first `.recv()` read, the server steps right into a second, again blocking `.recv()`, where it remains waiting infinitely long ( as instructed ) in all cases no other message was delivered from [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system) external worlds to the hands of your local `Context()` instance. In any such case, the blocking-form of the `.recv()` simply never returns.

If in doubts, whether there is anything at all to read, the **`POLLIN`** event is the conditio sine qua non, and using another test, until a call to **`socket.getsockopt( zmq.RCVMORE )`** returns **`False`**, upon all first received message multipart-elements ( if any present ) were already depleted.

Given your client-code opts to use a **`REQ`**-archetype, it will never send any message, without having first been asked to do so from server. This if your server-code is hanging inside the above explained ( conceptually ill-defined ) blocking `.recv()`, it will never ask "another" `REQ`-client to reply.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, Zmq cannot serve two clients? One after the another? Like reply to first client and do the second one. Can you pleasesuggest me another library if this method to work?

Comment: Or may be i should use Queue device which comes along with pyzmq?

Comment: ZeroMQ can absolutely serve many more clients, than just the two. The problem is in your expected rigid order of events. **[tag:distributed-system]** cannot be rigid in such cases, as your code is outside of control of many external events and factors, so it is designer's responsibility to design-in all such types of robustness and ( best ) avoid any chance for blocking. If you are serious into going distributed, the best next step is to read a great book from Pieter HINTJENS - " **Code Connected: Volume 1** ", it is worth time & efforts to better understand the new landscapes of this domain.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have a scenario where i need to find all connected devices on my subnet and start the req-recv for the clients. So, I am confused about how to tackle this and i thought of using two threads, one to handle udp broadcast and one to do req-rep pattern. Do you suggest any idea?

Comment: You ask another question after another question after answer to the MCVE-formulated post was provided. Going finally into the " *( actually ) **I have a scenario where I need to find ...*** " is asking others to do a job of your own. This is not a way StackOverflow Community was founded to work with. Feel free to open another question, showing first what have you done, why, what failed to work and how did you try to fix it, before asking others to help. These are the ethic levels to keep with. If yet not sure about steps&measures, re-read the StackOverflow Help on MCVE-based questions, ok?

Comment: Yes, I will try posting what i have tried so far in other question and thanks